# Logical LOOP in Visual C#

Tags: c#, loops

i am writting a small music application and i play every 88 keys this way:

```
if (nutka == "A0" && msg.Velocity < 28)
{
    PlayEngine.Instance.PlaySound("-12dB_01");
}
else if (nutka == "A0" && msg.Velocity < 55 && msg.Velocity > 27)
{
    PlayEngine.Instance.PlaySound("-9dB_01");
}
else if (nutka == "A0" && msg.Velocity < 82 && msg.Velocity > 54)
{
    PlayEngine.Instance.PlaySound("-6dB_01");
}
else if (nutka == "A0" && msg.Velocity < 106 && msg.Velocity > 81)
{
    PlayEngine.Instance.PlaySound("-3dB_01");
}
else if (nutka == "A0" && msg.Velocity < 128 && msg.Velocity > 105)
{
    PlayEngine.Instance.PlaySound("0dB_01");
}
```

As you can see, i have 5 velocity ranges for one key for signals from my external midi controller. And i have similar 88 if statments, the only thins is changing is: name of "nutka" and the last digit in the name of playing file

(for example here we can play one note "A0" by the use of 5 files depend on velocity: -12dB_01, -9dB_01, -6dB_01, -3dB_01 and 0dB_01, and this looks realy bad in code for 88 notes...

Have no idea how to make shorter version or maybe short loop... any help is apprreciated.

Comment: A list and and some lamdas will be your friend here!

Comment: And what if `nutka == "A1"` or `nutka == "B4"`? Can you *compute* the final string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can concatinate the string:

```
var keys = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// fill dictionary with relations: A0 -> 01
keys.Add("A0", "01");

var key  = keys[nutka];

int velocity;
if (msg.Velocity < 28)
    velocity = -12
else if (msg.Velocity < 55)
    velocity = -9
else if (msg.Velocity < 82)
    velocity = -6
else if (msg.Velocity < 106)
    velocity = -3
else
    velocity = 0;

string tune = String.Format("{0}dB_{1}", velocity, key);
PlayEngine.Instance.PlaySound(tune);
```

The filling of the dictionary can be done once.

Answer (score 2):

You would typically do this by having a List of items which describe your functionality.

For example, given a simple class

```
public class SoundInfo
{
    public string Nutka{get;set;}
    public int MinVelocity {get;set;}
    public int MaxVelocity {get;set;}
    public string SoundFile{get;set;}
}
```

You store them in a `List<SoundInfo>`

```
public List<SoundInfo> sounds
   = new List<SoundInfo>()
{
    new SoundInfo { Nutka = "A0", MinVelocity = 0, MaxVelocity = 28, SoundFile="-12dB_01" },
    new SoundInfo { Nutka = "A0", MinVelocity = 28, MaxVelocity = 55 SoundFile="-6dB_01" },
    new SoundInfo { Nutka = "A0", MinVelocity = 55, MaxVelocity = 82, SoundFile="-3dB_01" },

};
```

You could then simply look up the right record based on the values of `nutka` and `msg.Velocity`:

```
var item = sounds.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Nutka == nutka 
                && msg.Velocity < s.MaxVelocity && msg.Velocity >= s.MinVelocity);
if(item == null)
    throw new Exception ("No sound found!!");
PlayEngine.Instance.PlaySound(item.SoundFile);
```

Comment: Thank you Jamiec it looks like the best way to make it works and look "shorter" :)

Muhammad Zeeshan - this way i need to make again another 87 statements for each note A0, A1, B0, B1.......